# How can I build wabt tools in release on Linux

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I want to build The **WebAssembly Binary Toolkit** in release on Linux. I followed the instructions given below but it always creates debug binaries  .

https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt#building-using-cmake-directly-linux-and-macos

The command I used to generate the binaries:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ cmake --build .
```

It generates the wasm-objdump but when I run below command It seems to be debug binary

```
$file wasm-objdump
```

O/P:

```
wasm-objdump: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a7194a75b0079b4278a2cb380e140876071b8642, with debug_info, not stripped
```

To be more specific, I want release version of wasm-objdump.

As @yflelion mentioned below "build verbose mode to see the exact commands executed"

Below are the command I ran:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON
$ cmake --build .
```

O/P:

```
Scanning dependencies of target wasm-objdump
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build'
[ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/src/tools/wasm-objdump.cc.o
/usr/bin/c++  -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS=1 -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/third_party/gtest/googletest -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/third_party/gtest/googletest/include  -std=c++11 -Wold-style-cast -fno-exceptions -O3 -DNDEBUG   -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wpointer-arith -g -Wuninitialized -Wno-clobbered -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/src/tools/wasm-objdump.cc.o -c /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/src/tools/wasm-objdump.cc
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/src/binary-reader-objdump.cc.o
/usr/bin/c++  -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS=1 -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/third_party/gtest/googletest -I/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/third_party/gtest/googletest/include  -std=c++11 -Wold-style-cast -fno-exceptions -O3 -DNDEBUG   -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wpointer-arith -g -Wuninitialized -Wno-clobbered -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/src/binary-reader-objdump.cc.o -c /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/src/binary-reader-objdump.cc
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable wasm-objdump
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11 -Wold-style-cast -fno-exceptions -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/src/tools/wasm-objdump.cc.o CMakeFiles/wasm-objdump.dir/src/binary-reader-objdump.cc.o  -o wasm-objdump libwabt.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build'
[ 73%] Built target wasm-objdump
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/wasm2c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/wasm2c.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build'
cd /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build /home/kumarpr/Praveer_wabt/wabt/build/CMakeFiles/wasm2c.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
```

Comment: can you build in verbose mode to see the exact commands executed and add them to the question?

Comment: @yflelion  Added.

Comment: you have -g option in your command line. did you add it in your Cmakelist ?

Comment: No, I didn't add anything . But, I believe its because of this line of code .

https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L142

Comment: Yes it is because this line.

Comment: which means it will always generate the binary with debug info. If I remove `-g` and build it the generated binary size becomes only 723 KB. not sure if its correct  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224892/discussion-between-praveer-kumar-and-yflelion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this project the debug information are generated by default because of th -g option added with `add_definitions`.

```
-g

Produce debugging information in the operating system’s native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF). GDB can work with this debugging information.

On most systems that use stabs format, -g enables use of extra debugging information that only GDB can use; this extra information makes debugging work better in GDB but probably makes other debuggers crash or refuse to read the program. If you want to control for certain whether to generate the extra information, use -gstabs+, -gstabs, -gxcoff+, -gxcoff, or -gvms (see below).
```

To make this project build in release mode and debug mode this option should be deleted from `add_definitions` and added instead in `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`.

If the goal is only to compile in release mode you can only delete this option from the add_definitions. Removing this option should have no effect on the operation of the code.